# Autonomy - Force reindexing without losing data

Tags: autonomy

I need to add a new parameter to my Autonomy HTTP fetch configuration.

```
ImportFieldOp2=Expand
ImportFieldOpApplyTo2=AUTHOR
ImportFieldOpParam2=;;AUTHOR_M
```

I stop the HTTPFetch service and, after the config modification, I started the service.

The problem is that the change made is only applied to the new documents. 
The old documents don't have the new parameter.

If I remove all the documents indexed works, but is a production environment and I can't do that.

How can i force the indexation of the old documents without losing data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Content engine parameter KillDuplicates.

KillDuplicates=DREREFERENCE should do what you want.

A full re-crawl would be required to update the existing documents with the new ones.